# RNMapbox (React Native Mapbox) Filter by active place in cluster

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mapbox, rnmapbox-maps

I have a mapbox in react native using `@rnmapbox` and I'm attempting to highlight a cluster if the currently selected `activePlace` is inside that cluster. I'm having some difficulty figuring out the best way to do this.

Here's some sample code that outlines how things are currently set up:

```js
// The `activePlace` is actually user selected, but for this example I'll just pre-populate it with dummy data
const [activePlace, setActivePlace] = useState<Place>(defaultPlace)
const [features, setFeatures] = useState<FeatureCollection>(defaultFeatures)

return (
  <Mapbox.MapView
    ...
  />
    <Mapbox.Camera ... />
    <Mapbox.ShapeSource 
      id="places" 
      shape={{
        type: 'FeatureCollection',
        features,
      }}
      cluster
    >
      <Mapbox.CircleLayer
        id="clusteredPoints"
        filter={['has', 'point_count']}
      />
      <Mapbox.CircleLayer
        id="placesPoints"
        style={styles.place}
        filter={'all', ['!has', 'point_count'], ['!=', 'id', activePlace ? activePlace.id : '']}
      />
      <Mapbox.CircleLayer
        id="placesPoints"
        style={styles.placeActive}
        filter={'all', ['!has', 'point_count'], ['==', 'id', activePlace ? activePlace.id : '']}
      />
    </Mapbox.ShapeSource>
  </Mapbox.MapView>
)
```

The effect I want is that when the user has selected a place that is inside a cluster, I want to be able to filter on that so I can create specific styles for that clustered circle (i.e. make the border wider or a different color so the user knows the place is inside that cluster).

My instinct is telling me I could add another `CircleLayer` and add some extra filters, but I don't know if that's correct or what filters could be used to get this effect.